# How to write recursive descent parser for call expression?

Tags: parsing

I have next rules:

```
factor ::= id | func | ( expr )  
func ::= id ( list )  
list ::= list , expr | expr
```

I write simple descent parser:

```
function factor() {
  if (lookahead === "(") {
    match("(");
    expr();
    return match(")");
  } else {
    id();
  } // How to understand what it can be a func here?
};
​
function func() {
  id();
  match("(");
  list();
  match(")");
};
```

But how to combine func and id?

Comment: Often you need to order the tests in a parse routine, to ensure that the longest match gets captured. Try calling "func" in factor, before you try for the id.   You'll need some support for backing up the input stream when a syntax matching entity fails, or you need to left-factor the common part of the rules. Alternative: lift the func rule content into the factor rule.

Comment: Your parser is missing a lot of support for handling syntax  errors.  See my SO answer on how to write recursive descent parsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Comment: I'm trying to do left-factor when i can. How to do it here? Or i need lookahead for 2? Or push back token in func rule fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left factor the grammar like this:

```
 factor ::= id ( '(' list ')' )? | '(' expr ')' 
 list ::=  expr ( ',' expr );
```

Note careful distinction of literal parentheses '(' and ')'
and syntax grouping parentheses ( ... )

Coding left to the reader :-}

Check my answer on how to write recursive parser for details.

Comment: This still is same. I think recover will be best solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "same" here.  In this form, an RE parser never has to back up the input stream.   If you want convenience of expression, or fideltity to an original grammar, then rewinding the input stream to a recovery point (e.g., where it was when a recognition routine was entered) is convenient, at the price of more overhead in tracking tokens to enable rewinding to occur.